# Correct HTML code for a box with dashed border

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to write HTML code for the picture below:

[image]

The CSS looks like this:

```
    .borderbox {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    position: absolute;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 5%;

}

h3.header-3 {
    font-size: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00a0df;
    margin: 4px auto 17px;
}

p.paragraph-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00a0df;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: HelveticaNeueBold;

}
```

The text is `<p> visa fler bästsäljare </p> <h3>+<h3>`.

The code I have gotten help with so far is:

```
    <body>
    <div class="borderbox">
        <h3 class="header-3">+</h3>
        <p class="paragraph-text">visa fler bästsäljare</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

The only issue is that this code does not create the image as I posted. URL to the website [URL](http://www.shopstuff.se/). Scroll down a bit. The browser I am testing this on is Google Chrome.

Comment: Show your real code (the one you posted is invalid and does not contain any `class` attributes, yet your CSS code uses class selectors) and state exactly what is wrong with the result (and mention the browser(s) tested).

Comment: I have edited my question now since I have gotten some answers so far. Although the answers are not fully satisfying.

Comment: I think you mean that on your live page, a dashed border appears only above the borderbox. However, that is apparently caused by something else on the page, not by the code included in the question. (BTW, most computers don’t have HelveticaNeueBold, so you should probably use e.g. `font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold` instead. But this affects of course just the text, not the border.)

Comment: Thank you for the useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the

```
.borderbox {
    height: 90%;
}
```

then the dashed border should work as you expected.

Comment: You are awsome mister. One more thing. Is there any posibility to have this to have the whole width and length? Please see my URL again.

Comment: @Joneskvist What do you mean by whole width and length?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/e7Levykn/

I don't think you can style border with one argument. You would have to use

`border-style` , `border-color`, `border-width`.

EDIT: Nvm about the border thing. Your css-code should work, it works in the jsfiddle. Maybe your elements in html don't have the right classes

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, but it changes the entire fonts in the whole website. How can I do this by adding a class or id maybe? I only want it in one specific case.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to use a class along with the h3 and p. Same way you already did in your css file. But don't forget to add the lastproductinlist class to your html element.

For example like here: http://jsfiddle.net/e7Levykn/6/

Comment: Please have a look at my site, it does not become as good as in the js fiddle. [link](http://www.shopstuff.se/)

Comment: Can you show me a part of the html where that div should be displayed?

Comment: I am using a wordpress theme and you insert this html in a Box that is called "RAW HTML".

Answer (score 0):

Use css `border-style` property.

```
.selector{
border-style: dashed;
}
```

or like this

```
.selector{
    border:2px dashed #F1F1F1;
}
```